# Where's the official doc for RSpec's instance_double method that outline how you can configure the method's return value?

Tags: ruby, rspec

For below code in spec:

```
let(:my_model) { instance_double(MyModel, is_happy: true) }
```

I want to confirm what `is_happy: true` does exactly.

I think it stub the `is_happy` instance method of `MyModel` double and make it always return `true` in the spec, but I want to see official RSpec doc confirming this.

I can see this [RSpec doc](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-10/docs/verifying-doubles/using-an-instance-double), but it doesn't mention the method stubbing part.

Where in the doc is this documented and how should I navigate docs around RSpec?

Comment: The docs you linked do tell that the methods being stubbed like you described: _An instance_double is the most common type of verifying double. It takes a class name or object as its first argument, then verifies that **any methods being stubbed** would be present on an instance of that class. In addition, when it receives messages, it verifies that the provided arguments are supported by the method signature, both in terms of arity and allowed or required keyword arguments, if any._

Comment: @spickermann Thank you, but I was more like looking for the exact method definition like what max described in the answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Yard documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-mocks/RSpec%2FMocks%2FExampleMethods:instance_double):

> `instance_double(doubled_class, stubs)`
>
> Parameters:
>
> - doubled_class (String, Class)
> - stubs (Hash) — hash of message/return-value pairs

`is_happy: true` will make the double return `true` when sent the the message `is_happy`.

RSpec has both the normal API documentation which is generated by Yard from the code and the guide style documenation that you have linked. Its quite common to have both in a well documented project since they serve different purposes.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for.